# TS2339: Property 'xxx' does not exist on type '{ new (): xxx; prototype: xxx; }'

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a declaration for my project。

like this:

```
// storage.d.ts
interface Session {
  get: (key: string) => string;
  save: (key: string, value: string) => void;
  remove: (key: string, value: string) => void;
  clear: () => void;
}

declare namespace Storage {
  function get(key: string): string;
  function save(key: string, value: string, time?: number);
  function remove(key: string);
  function clear(): void;
  const session: Session
  function on(key: string, fn: Function): void
  function off(key: string, fn?: Function): void;
}

export as namespace Storage;

export = Storage;
```

I posted the project to NPM.

Now I've introduced this package in a project.

```
import Storage from 'xxx'

Storage.get('xxx')
```

Oddly enough, VSCode doesn't warn of any errors. But the console keeps prompting for errors。

```
 error  in E:\my_ptoject\node_manage\admin-permission-demo\src\models\login.ts

[tsl] ERROR in E:\my_ptoject\node_manage\admin-permission-demo\src\models\login.ts(35,23)
      TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type '{ new (): Storage; prototype: Storage; }'.

 error  in E:\my_ptoject\node_manage\admin-permission-demo\src\models\login.ts

[tsl] ERROR in E:\my_ptoject\node_manage\admin-permission-demo\src\models\login.ts(36,20)
      TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type '{ new (): Storage; prototype: Storage; }'.
```